# Vaadin and Dependency Injection Frameworks

Tags: java, dependency-injection, vaadin

I'm starting the development of a new application based on Vaadin. I'm a big fan of developing TDD and therefore writing easy to test code. When it comes to Vaadin I see some tutorials on the web where people say they use i.e. Spring because they are so great Spring fans but I never see the point of it. As I see it Vaadins API doesn't allow much Unit Testing (I can check what Components are in a window and what their caption ist etc. but that's nearly all) and the Vaadin guys refer everywhere when the question comes to JUnit to their Testbench for testing the UI Code. 
My question now is does it make any sense trying to use CDI, Spring or anything else for the Vaadin Code or isn't there any great benefit from it so that I can skip on that and only use it on the server side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DI makes about the same sense with Vaadin as with any other framework.

I would recommend implementing the usual MVC or MVP patterns and doing TDD at least for your controllers. Testbench should be great for acceptance\functional testing, although I haven't used it so far.

https://bitbucket.org/dwijnand/spring-navigator7/src here is a good start for using spring with vaadin.

Comment: Calling `SpringWebApplication.getBean()` each time is not handy. Any ideas how to make everything `@Autowire`d?

Comment: Everything is autowired, this method is only used to wire up vaadin and spring internally and is not intended to be used from application code.